# Storing a condition as a variable

Tags: c#

The bool will be saved as true or false in the constructor. What is the simplest way of storing a condition where the variables will change and be recalculated in the future?

Essentially, I want to create a new class and ask it "was that conditional statement you wrote earlier now true or false?"

```
public class MyClass
{
    public bool Condition { get; }
    public MyClass(bool condition)
    {
        Condition = condition;
    }
}

public class MyOtherClass
{

    int foo = 1;
    int goo = 2;
    MyClass myClass;

    public MyOtherClass()
    {
        myClass = new MyClass(foo > goo);
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        foo = 3;
        if (myClass.Condition)
            //Do Something
    }

}
```

Comment: Pass `Predicate`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.predicate-1?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Changing the value of _foo_ doens't change the boolean stored inside MyClass. The evaluation of the condition is done only at the constructor point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to use a predicate, for example, using the built in `Func` generic type:

```
public class MyClass
{ 
  public MyClass(Func<bool> predicate)
  {
    this.Predicate = predicate;
  }

  public Func<bool> Predicate { get; }
}

var bah = new MyClass(() => foo > baz)

if (bah.Predicate())
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly.